# Adding a string to a extensionattribute in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I try to add value X to a Active Directory Member Y that has already some values in extensionAttribute10. How do I add a specific string into that? Also I want to scan the extensionAttribute and remove a specific entry.

```
Testparameters:
$ThisUser = "Testaccount01"
@{extensionAttribute10=Computer01, Computer02}
$adding = "Computer03"
$delete = "Computer01"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ThisUser = "Test"
$delete = "Computer2"
$add = "Computer3"
$user = Get-ADUser -Identity $ThisUser -Properties extensionAttribute10
$newAttribute = [string[]]($user.extensionAttribute10 -split '[,\s]+' | ?{$_ -ne $delete}) + $add
Set-ADUser $thisUser -Replace @{extensionAttribute10=$newAttribute}
```

Comment: you cast the output to an string array:

Comment: The only thing missing from your code is the re-conversion of the array of tokens to a single string with separators; you can simply append `-join ', '` to the RHS of your `$newAttribute = ...` assignment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

assuming the target is a user account:

```
#Replace existing value with a new one
set-aduser -identity [userSamAccountName] -replace @{extensionAttribute10=$value}

#Add new value to 
set-aduser -identity [userSamAccountName] -add @{extensionAttribute10=$value}
```

If your target is a different object type, e.g. a computer use the related cmdlets, the syntax is equal....

As response to your comment: Sure the code does work but you need to consider the datatype of the target attribute, which is not an array it's a single value. So if you need to store multiple values there you need to transform the array into a delimited string, e.g.:

```
$value = @('comp1','comp2')
$valueString = $value -join ","
set-aduser -identity [userSamAccountName] -add @{extensionAttribute10=$valueString}
```

But be aware that this attribute has a size limit.

Ok based on your code sample, you cast the output as string array ([string[]]) but as outlined earlier you need a string and not an array:

your code

```
$newAttribute = [string[]]($user.extensionAttribute10 -split '[,\s]+' | ?{$_ -ne $delete}) + $add
```

replace with:

```
$valueArray = @($user.extensionAttribute10 -split ',' | ?{$_ -ne $delete})
$valueArray += $add
$valueString = $valueArray -join ","

set-aduser -identity [userSamAccountName] -replace @{extensionAttribute10=$valueString}
```

Comment: Doesnt work, it says, that the attribute only can have a single value but i gave him multiple

Comment: Ah okay, but as soon as i tried it its the same error

Comment: show the code....